# Add a new iPhone View above everything, including the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In an application I'm developing, everything starts from a navigation controller, which then loads up several pages.

My question is, how can I load up a new view ABOVE this? The closest I've got is to do this in the App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{   
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    [self readDataFromDatabase];

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

    // Add this
    [window addSubview:[newViewController view]];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

However this will load the view half way across the screen with no way of having it start at (0,0). Do anyone have a better suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can show regular views on top of everything by showing it as a modal view. Here is a sample project. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3656129/ModalViewExample.zip

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I didn't mention this in the question but you can't give a modal view and reduced alpha and see whats underneath it seems!

Comment: This method does not show the view above the Navigation Controller.

Comment: Yes it does. Here is a picture. If you looked at it before and saw the wrong screen, I fixed the link. http://i1106.photobucket.com/albums/h377/enbr95/Screenshot2010-11-04at81451AM.png

Comment: It doesn't. I'm having a problem where I added a view after adding the view controller and when I call a modal view from said view controller the bar is above the modal too.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you upload a sample project?